# Type mismatch error

Tags: excel, vba

I am  new to VBA and getting type mismatch errors in the following code.

I am getting error for integer `j`. I have changed it to all other data types but still the same.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer

    Set rng1 = Range("A:A")
    Set rng2 = Range("B:B")

    j = Application.WorksheetFunction.Lookup(2, 1 / (rng1 <> ""), rng1)
    k = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(j, rng1, 0)

    i = 0

    For i = i + 1 To k
        If Cells(i, 1) Mod 2 = 0 Then
            Cells(i, 2) = "Even"
        Else: Cells(i, 2) = "Odd"
        End If
    Next i

    MsgBox "There are " & Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng2, "Even") _
        & " Even and " & Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng2, "Odd") & " Odd numbers"

End Sub
```

Comment: You can't compare an array to a string (i.e. `rng1 <> ""` is not valid and will give a type mismatch).

Comment: thank you. That means i can use last row function only. Please tell how this formula can be used in VBA as the same works fine in Excel but not in VBA

Comment: If I am reading your code correctly, you were attempting to find the first row containing the value that is on the last occupied row of column A.  Is that correct?  And then you are trying to work out how many even numbers occur up to that point and also how many odd numbers - but you want to exclude from the count anything beyond that first occurrence of the last value in column A.  Is that correct?  So if cells A1:A9 contained `1, 2, 2.7, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3` you are trying to calculate 1 even and 3 odd (i.e. the counts down to A4 only).  Is that correct?

Comment: the first two of your questions are totally correct. But i did not get your last question including the example.

Comment: I am trying to see all the numbers in a column to whatever rows the list is dynamically changed, everytime the user inlcudes more and more numbers, so that first i see the last non empty row and then calculate the number of evens and odds from 1st row to last non empty row. As already told before, i am new to VBA and not excel and hence any silly queries and expectation ragarding VBA coding may please be forgiven. Anyways thanks a ton for your prompt replies

Comment: I am an Electrical Engineer and hence trying to solve these VBA codes to enable me to put the code to greater use in my daily electrical calculations involving huge lists. just for your information.

Answer (score 0):

My comment:

> If I am reading your code correctly, you were attempting to find the first row containing the value that is on the last occupied row of column A. Is that correct? And then you are trying to work out how many even numbers occur up to that point and also how many odd numbers - but you want to exclude from the count anything beyond that first occurrence of the last value in column A. Is that correct? ...

Your reply:

> the first two of your questions are totally correct.

Example data:

[image]

---

If you really want to find the first row containing the value that is on the last occupied row of column A, i.e. the first row containing a `3` in the example data above, and determine the number of odds/evens to that point and exclude from the count anything beyond that point then you can use the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()    
    Dim lastUsedRow As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Odds As Long: Odds = 0
    Dim Evens As Long: Evens = 0

    With ActiveSheet

        'Find the last used row in column A (row 9 in example data)
        lastUsedRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        'Find first row containing the data from the last used row
        '(i.e. the first row containing a 3 in the example data, i.e. row 4)
        lastRow = Application.Match(.Cells(lastUsedRow, "A").Value, .Range("A:A"), 0)

        'Loop from first row to last row
        For i = 1 To lastRow

            'Decide whether the nearest integer to the value in the cell
            'is odd or even
            If .Cells(i, "A").Value Mod 2 = 0 Then
                .Cells(i, "B").Value = "Even"
                Evens = Evens + 1
            Else
                .Cells(i, "B").Value = "Odd"
                Odds = Odds + 1
            End If

        Next i

        MsgBox "There are " & Evens & " Even and " & Odds & " Odd numbers"
    End With
End Sub
```

---

If, however, you want to do your calculations on **all** the rows then you can use the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()    
    Dim lastUsedRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Odds As Long: Odds = 0
    Dim Evens As Long: Evens = 0

    With ActiveSheet

        'Find the last used row in column A (row 9 in example data)
        lastUsedRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        'Loop from first row to last used row
        For i = 1 To lastUsedRow

            'Decide whether the nearest integer to the value in the cell
            'is odd or even
            If .Cells(i, "A").Value Mod 2 = 0 Then
                .Cells(i, "B").Value = "Even"
                Evens = Evens + 1
            Else
                .Cells(i, "B").Value = "Odd"
                Odds = Odds + 1
            End If

        Next i

        MsgBox "There are " & Evens & " Even and " & Odds & " Odd numbers"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I was referring to the 2nd code that u have written. i already used that and found the answer. anyways thanks for educating on the first code also. But now i have some other queries. I ahve written the code below. Please tell me the use of dot before "cells" and "rows"

Comment: Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, i As Integer, LastRow As Long
Set rng1 = Range("A:A")
Set rng2 = Range("B:B")

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'finding the last non blank row in column 1

i = 0

For i = i + 1 To LastRow

    If Cells(i, 1) Mod 2 = 0 Then
    Cells(i, 2) = "Even"
    Else
    Cells(i, 2) = "Odd"
    
    End If
    
    
Next i

MsgBox "There are " & Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng2, "Even") & " Even and " & Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng2, "Odd") & " Odd numbers"

End Sub

Comment: In a `With` block any `.` at the start of something is assumed to refer to the object of the `With`, so within a `With ActiveSheet` the `.Rows` is a shortcut for `ActiveSheet.Rows` - it saves a lot of typing.  It also makes it easier if you want to change the object from `ActiveSheet` to `Worksheets("Sheet4")` (for instance) because you just need to change `With ActiveSheet` to `With Worksheets("Sheet4")` and you are done.